# Codeigniter recursive get all ids

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, recursion

I would like to get all IDs with recursion from 1 table. I managed to echo those variables but when I tried to put it into array I failed. Here is the string version:

```
public function get_numProducts($cid)
{
    $this->db->select('cat_id');
    $this->db->from('ci_categories');
    $this->db->where('cat_child',$cid);
    $q = $this->db->get();

    $result = $q->result();

    $i=0;
    $a="";
    foreach($result as $mainCategory)
    {
        $a .= $mainCategory->cat_id;
        $a .= $this->get_numProducts($mainCategory->cat_id);
    }

    return $a;

}
```

When calling this function with param "4" I get string output: 89. Which is good. But I would like to have output an array(4,8,9). Thanks for help

**EDIT:**

2nd version

```
public function get_numProducts($cid)
{
    $this->db->select('cat_id');
    $this->db->from('ci_categories');
    $this->db->where('cat_child',$cid);
    $q = $this->db->get();

    $result = $q->row();
    $n = $q->num_rows();

    if ($n > 0)
    {
        $array[] = $result->cat_id." ";
        $array[] = $this->get_numProducts($result->cat_id);
    }


    return $array;

}
```

This version returns array however multidimensional:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '8 ' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '9 ' (length=2)
      1 => null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to pass the array be reference to each iteration of the function ..

```
public function get_numProducts($cid, &$array)
```

..

```
$array[] = $cid;

if ($n > 0) $this->get_numProducts($result->cat_id, $array);
```

Comment: Working fine. But how could I set the 1st value "4" as the start value of that array ?